# What happen when we create new Class in @Bean, and use in @Bean in another @Bean

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have beans:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Integer> currenciesCodesMap(@Value("${readTimeoutMillis}") int readTimeout,
                                               @Value("${connectTimeoutMillis}") int connectTimeout,
                                               UriFactory uriFactory) {
    System.out.println("currenciesCodesMap");
    RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate(readTimeout + 1, connectTimeout + 1);
    List<Map> maps = Arrays.asList(Objects.requireNonNull(restTemplate.getForObject(uriFactory.getProgressiveCurrencyRates(), Map[].class)));
        Map<String, Integer> currenciesCodesMap = maps.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                map -> (String) map.get("code"),
                map -> (Integer) map.get("id")
        ));
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate codesConverterRestTemplate(@Value("${readTimeoutMillis}") int readTimeout,
                                                   @Value("${connectTimeoutMillis}") int connectTimeout,
                                                   UriFactory uriFactory) {
        System.out.println("codesConverterRestTemplate");
        return getRestTemplate(readTimeout, connectTimeout);
    }
@Bean
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(int readTimeout, int connectTimeout) {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableCookieManagement().build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        factory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        factory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);

        System.out.println("getRestTemplate");

        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }
```

I dont want to create new RestTemplate in every bean, so I decided to create it in another bean and inject this third bean, in two first beans. On startup, I see that(with System.out.println) my beans created only ones(because they are singletons), but I cant understand how it can be, because I use different parameters to call third bean in first two beans. So my Question is: how this whole thing works. How many times new RestTemplate(factory) will be calling, how it could be one call to third bean if I use it in two places with different parameters. And is it a good approach to create RestTemplate in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `@Configuration` class will not instantiate a new object every time a method annotated with `@Bean` calls another method annotated with `@Bean`. Consider this example:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public String bean2(){
        String bean = bean1("bean2");
        System.out.println("bean2: " + bean);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public String bean3(){
        String bean = bean1("bean3");
        System.out.println("bean3: " + bean);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public String bean1(@Autowired(required = false) String name){
        System.out.println("bean1 " + name);
        return name;
    }
}
```

The output is as follows because `bean2()` is executed first:

```
bean1 bean2
bean2: bean2
bean3: bean2
```

This is the relevant [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton):

> To put it another way, when you define a bean definition and it is
>   scoped as a singleton, the Spring IoC container creates exactly one
>   instance of the object defined by that bean definition. This single
>   instance is stored in a cache of such singleton beans, and all
>   subsequent requests and references for that named bean return the
>   cached object. The following image shows how the singleton scope
>   works:

In this case, a method annotated with `@Bean` *is* a bean definition.

Also:

> All @Configuration classes are subclassed at startup-time with CGLIB.
>   In the subclass, the child method checks the container first for any
>   cached (scoped) beans before it calls the parent method and creates a
>   new instance.

In other words, calling a method annotated with `@Bean` should return the same bean every time, regardless of arguments. In your case, I'd consider it undefined behavior, as the order of instantiation isn't guaranteed unless you use options like `depends-on` or `SmartLifecycle`.